# Postgres Serializable does not seem to work as described

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions, serializable

I am new to Postgres, and have not looked very carefully at transaction isolation in the past. However, I am not seeing the behaviour I would expect according to the Postgres docs. In particular, it seems I am not getting an error where expected for stale reads. This is for Postgres 12.

Assuming a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE public.transactiontest (id int8 NULL, col_a varchar NULL);
INSERT INTO public.transactiontest (id, col_a) VALUES (1, 'aaa'), (2, 'bbb');
```

Executing on two sessions...

```
--Session 1
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; --1
SELECT id, col_a FROM public.transactiontest; --2

--Session 2
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; --3
SELECT id, col_a FROM public.transactiontest; --4

--Session 1
UPDATE public.transactiontest SET col_a = 'ccc' where id = 1; --5
COMMIT; --6

--Session 2
COMMIT; --7
```

I would have thought I would get an error at line 7, but the commit there goes through. It seems this would violate the docs

> as if transactions had been executed one after another, serially,
>   rather than concurrently.

because ordering the sessions 1 then 2 would give different results for line 4 than ordering 2 then 1.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If session 2 were run before session 1, the result would be the same.

Consequently, the execution “first session2, then session 1” is a *serialization* of the workload.

That means that the workload is serializable.

It does not matter that session 1 started before session 2 in reality. As long as there is an equivalent serial execution, we are good.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had a mistake in the update statement. I've fixed it, so that now the value is changed from the initial. How would this affect your explanation?

Comment: It makes no difference. Try it yourself: first as you did in your question, then serialized (first all statements from session 2, followed by all statements from session 1). You will see that the result is the same in both cases.

Comment: If I ran session 1 before session 2, the value I would read in session 2 would be 'ccc'. Doing the opposite, and I would read 'aaa'.

Comment: Right. And the latter also happens if you perform the SQL statements in your question. So these two executions are logically equivalent.

Comment: From the docs... "it monitors for conditions which could make execution of a concurrent set of serializable transactions behave in a manner inconsistent with all possible serial (one at a time) executions" It explicitly says "all", not just one possible execution.

Comment: Exactly. It is not inconsistent with all serial executions, because it is consistent with one serial execution.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I was reading it as "not consistent with all possible serial executions", not "inconsistent with", which is a subtle but critical distinction. It might have helped if they had written something more obvious, such as "not consistent with at least one possible serial execution."

Comment: It is always nice to see that flash of light when "Heureka" strikes. Well worth the effort :^)

Comment: I spent an embarrassingly large amount of time on this. Thanks again :)